# Chrome for Android: Hide horizontal scrollbar when not scrolling

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, scrollbar, overflow

I have a horizontally scrolling div. On mobile devices, **I would like to hide the scrollbar when the content is stationary**. It works this way on Safari on an iPad, but with Chrome on an Android tablet, I see the horizontal scrollbar at all times.

CSS on my horizontally scrolling div:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

A CSS solution would be preferable but Javascript/JQuery works too if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, and turns out it was the `border-radius` property that prevents the scrollbar from hiding. Also, scrolling was much more smooth after removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure it doesn't happen as you described?

I just tested it on a tablet and a phone using a [test I wrote](http://jsbin.com/donus/latest) and I noticed the bottom div only has scroll bars when the user is scrolling horizontally.  When the content is stationary the scroll bars fade away in about a second.

[image: scrollbar visible whilst scrolling]
[image: Scrollbar gone]

Comment: Can't figure this one out. Your test site works as you described on my tablet, our css is exactly the same on that element, yet I'm still always seeing the scroll bar on my site. I'll have to keep poking around.